# Giving Battle.net realm items to an open character

Tags: diablo-ii, battle.net

I've found some good necromancer items on a Battle.net realm with my sorceress. I know the opposite is not possible, but is there any hack to give these items to a friend who plays single player and TCP/IP games?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is, but I'm pretty sure there are plenty of mods for diablo 2 which can allow characters to have any items/stats they want. You could try looking for something like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The closest you can come to this is to download a diablo 2 character editor and adding an item into your inventory (if its a ladder only item such as a rune word or a unique charm, you can just create a similar item with the same stats as the rune word).

Comment: This should do the trick for set or unique items. Would such editor allow to add ladder-only items to single player characters? And how about items that only have randomly generated mods (such as magic/rare/crafted items)? Are there any editors to create rare/crafted items with specific bonuses?

Comment: @sarmackie the editor will allow you set whatever bonuses you want onto an item, even those that are not normally possible, such as +7 to all skills and 250% resist all.  What you will have to do is to set the effects of the item to exactly match what the item is on the ladder.